# Neo4j Spatial Converting wkt values to something else

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-spatial

My application uses point queries to find stores based on a user's current location.

```
public class Store extends AbstractNode {

    @Indexed(indexType = IndexType.POINT, indexName = "ErrandLocation") 
    private String wkt;

   public void setLocation(float lat, float lon) {
      this.wkt = String.format("POINT( %.2f %.2f )",lat,lon);
   }
}
```

On saving a shop with 
           shop.setLocation (12, 12);
and I use the neo4j browser to inspect my nodes, the wkt value changes to POINT( 56.34 -2.80 ).

I do not understand why the value changes to this from POINT (12.00, 12.00).

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling `shop.setLocation` you are calling the `setLocation` method that you have shown in your question, which stores the properly formatted WKT string which is required by the spatial classes.:

```
public void setLocation(float lat, float lon) {
  this.wkt = String.format("POINT( %.2f %.2f )",lat,lon);
}
```

If you require access to the raw lat/lon for your own purposes, stick them in different properties and they will be persisted too.